# redirect 301 old url to new url

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, terms, site-url

I created a custom post type (collections) and taxonomy (collection_categories) with 4 terms (paintings, drawings, sculptures, past sales),

now I want to change my site url,

old url is www.mysitename.com/collections/post-name,

I made a custom post type rewrite "collections" which is now "collection" and I added the related taxonomy terms in the url,

now is www.mysitename.com/collection/paintings/post-name 
or www.mysitename.com/collection/drawings/post-name etc.

The url to redirect more than 150, so I wanted to know if there was an easy solution to this.

How can I make a redirect the old url to the new? Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you would have to add some re-write rules in your `.htaccess` file (unless there's a plugin that can allow more complex 301 redirect rules).

But, in your situation, if I understand correctly, it's simply not possible to do it in one generic rewrite rule, due to the logic of your new URLs...

If all of your collections are at `mysitename.com/collections/post-name' then it's not going to be possible to write a general rewrite rule to redirect them all to the desired place.

Only you know which categories each needs to go into. So, you'll (unfortunately) have to write a line in .htaccess for every single post, in the following format:

```
Redirect 301 /collections/{post_x} http://mysitename.com/collection/{collection_category}/{post_x}
```

If ALL posts were going to go into one category, then you could write one generic rule. E.g. if you were to add all posts to the Paintings category:

```
RewriteRule ^collections/(.*)$ /collection/paintings/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But, yeah, if I understand you correctly, you are going to have to go with the former, and write one line for each post.

Comment: ok, thank anyway, The next time I will try to better Working On URL.